# How to postpone shutdown of a Windows Service

Tags: c#

I have a service written in c# to send out message to an eternal API using System.Net.WebClient.

How can I postpone shutdown to make sure my message result is return before the service can be shutdown by user?

Comment: Do you mean "power off"-Shutdown ? Or the receiver shut down and will not get your message?

Comment: @AlexH - he means the user shutting down the service. you need to delay the service from stopping by hooking into the service events. (OnStop) however what if the response NEVER comes?

Comment: Yah @Ahmed is right.

Comment: Are you looking to *prevent* shutdown, or just *postpone* it for a while until (hopefully) your API call returns? Very different question. You cannot prevent, but you can postpone.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten postpone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make sure my message is result is return before the service can be shutdown by user?

You cannot.

Consider if the remote system is running slowly: should the shutdown be delayed indefinitely?

And then consider what happens if power is lost (or another hardware failure): the system is off, no chance for a clean shutdown at all.

You cannot have any kind of reliability if you have single points of hardware failure.